# If there any way to unlock the keyguard using Intent objects

Tags: android, android-intent, keyguard

I am now trying to call `Context.StartActivity(intent)` on Android 5.0 device when the screen is locked (not secure lock) and I need to unlock the screen first.

I've learned to use some widow features in the target activity, but now I just want to start a chooser Activity to share a picture, so I can not modify the feature of the Activity since it is not created by me.

Another way is to use `KeyguardManager` to disable the keyguard, but I just want to dismiss, not disable it, because When I disable the keyguard, it can never lock the screen again.

Is there any way to do the job? Can I pass `Features` to the `Activity` via `Intent` or `Bundle`? or any other method to dismiss the keyguard? Or can I re-enable the keyguard when the sharing is done?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Couldn't you achieve what you need with a keylock widget?

Comment: I find way, using WindowManagerGlobal.getWindowManagerService().dismissKeyguard(); But this Class cannot be accessed by normal apps.